# What would you call this type of inference that TypeScript can not do?

Tags: typescript, terminology, type-inference, typescript-typings

Currently with TypeScript, if given a function to `map`, the array's type can not be inferred.

```
> let rfn1 = (a, fn:((x:number)=>number) ) => a.map(fn);

> .type rfn1

let rfn1: (a: any, fn: (x: number) => number) => any
```

You can see there `a` is of type `any` even though it must be of type `number[]` to provide a valid argument for a function of type `((x:number)=>number)`.

Likewise, you can see that this problem can be fixed with explicit types,

```
> let rfn2 = (a: number[], fn:((x:number)=>number) ) => a.map(fn);

> .type rfn2
let rfn9: (a: number[], fn: (x: number) => number) => number[]
```

What would you call the type of inference currently missing here that necessitates the explicit typing?

Comment: I'd say it would be a sort of [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-type).  If it were to perform that kind of inference, I would expect `a` to be inferred as type `{ map: (fn: (x: number) => number) => any };` and not necessarily `number[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your line of thinking... but it depends upon a number of unprovable assumptions. So I would call the widening of the `a` type:

> Widened type due to unprovable assumptions

If you work from the very inside, you have a function that is *compatible* with the callback function for `array.map`:

```
(value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => {}
```

We would have to assume that the function type we know about `((x: number) => number)` can only be intended to be used with `array.map` - and that's the first unprovable assumption.

Broadening our view by one step, we have `a.map(...)`. This *could* be `array.map`, but it might also be `geoAwesome.map` or literally anything else where we have created a `map` method. So assuming `a.map` is `array.map` is our second unprovable assumption.

Even combining the two assumptions, we still can't prove that `a` *must* be an array.

```
class NotArray {
  map(fn: (num: number) => number) {
    return fn(3);
  }
}

let rfn1 = (a, fn: ((x: number) => number)) => a.map(fn);

let res1 = rfn1([1, 2, 3], (x) => x);
console.log(res1);

let res2 = rfn1(new NotArray(), (x) => x);
console.log(res2);
```

Looking at this contrived example, you can see that `a` could be practically any type (as long as it has a compatible `map` method. Hence, `any`.

Only when we annotate the `a` parameter can the compiler prove that `a` isn't those other types - and now our `res2` example will generate an error.

```
let rfn1 = (a: number[], fn: ((x: number) => number)) => a.map(fn);
```

Comment: This is true, a major oversight (assumption) when i wrote this. I was basically trying to figure out this problem though which seems to be something totally different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243988/typescript-rejection-with-type-is-not-assignable-to-type-number I just thought that `.pipe()` and Ramda would have made this more confusing than needed.