# TypeScript rejection with `Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'number'`

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, ramda.js, definitelytyped

Let's say I create a simple function to double its input,

```
> let f1: (x: number) => number = x => x * 2;
> .type f1
let f1: (x: number) => number
```

If I want to take the first value and double it, I can do either

```
let f2 = R.pipe( R.take(1), f1 );
let f2 = R.pipe( R.head, f1 );
```

Both of these work `f2([5,4,3])` outside of TypeScript. However, with TypeScript I get,

```
> let f2 = R.pipe( R.take(1), f1 );
[eval].ts(6,29): error TS2345: Argument of type '(x: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: {}[]) => number'.
  Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
    Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

> let f2 = R.pipe( R.head, f1 );
[eval].ts(6,26): error TS2345: Argument of type '(x: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: string) => number'.
  Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

What am I doing wrong. I'm not even sure how to read,

> ```
> Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> ```

and, I don't see what cause the `string` in

> ```
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> ```

(I don't see a `string` anywhere).

Answer (score 4):

The general issue behind this is that TypeScript does really poorly with higher-order generic functions: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366.

In the majority of situations, when you pass a generic function (such as `R.take(n)` or `R.head`) into another (like `R.pipe`), instead of preserving free generic type parameters, TypeScript will automatically infer them. A lot of the time it infers these parameters as `{}`, its empty type.

In your second example with `R.head`, it infers string because `R.head` is actually defined with two overloads:

```
// from ramda/index.d.ts
head<T>(list: ReadonlyArray<T>): T | undefined;
head(list: string): string;
```

and since TypeScript can't decide yet which overload to use (you've given it neither a string nor an array) it just picks one. In my experience it picks the one defined last, more details on that here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13570

To make your instances work, you're going to need to manually fill in the generic parameters to get TypeScript to stop making the wrong guesses:

```
let f4 = R.pipe<number[], number, number>( R.head, f1 );
```

For your example with `R.take(n)`, according to Ramda it shouldn't actually work even if it typed, as it returns an array, not a singular value:

```
// from ramda/index.d.ts
take<T>(n: number): {
    (xs: string): string;
    (xs: ReadonlyArray<T>): T[];
};
```

Comment: You hit on every point and I really like that you linked the github issues. Brilliant answer. I was actually curious to know why `take(1)` works like that too (and I may ask a follow up because I am kind of interested in the history there). I'll throw down a bounty on this one (and mark it as accepted later) to help get you through the ranks on Stack Overflow. Stick around!

Comment: Do you think flow handles this better?

Comment: I don't have much experience or knowledge of Flowtype, but it does correctly handle [this toy example](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxsgpgHgGIBpEDi+AEgHwAUwA5gFyKV3YCUiAvKYflQBZ3m2EW7RMXxM+wRkI7FEAbwBQASABO6KCBVIGiZmw49KVSkyYBuBQF8FC0JFgJEAIzgAPTABUKANwCGAGxB0Og9xRA8AbQBdeQVERDUNLUQIv0D0KItrW3BoeCRwF3cvclSAqJDosI9Y+MTNJDSzRCsbCAQAZyhEGAATNhQ0dHIi-EK3cxsAeinEDu44EH9+jpAICHR0XoV2sA64f3QAOn84Yz7yAGYmI6g4bBhXLfJTCwUZuYWl-uBfGH8dp0DsdTudeuQAESXCE3O4PJ7g16AvbAk5ncgXa5HYBwOAAIV8Khe5iAA), while [TS fails](https://repl.it/repls/DearSteelblueConfigfiles).

Comment: A PR has been recently merged that may make TypeScript better at inferring these kinds of types in the future: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215